# Can other people in our world see Kirjava?

Tags: his-dark-materials, the-amber-spyglass

I've just finished watching series 3 of His Dark Materials (haven't read the books). During the course of the series...

> ... Will's daemon (named Kirjava by Serafina) becomes visible, both to him and others. I was wondering - once he returns to our world at the end of the series, is his daemon still visible to other people? It seems like it would make his later life complicated to have a cat following him everywhere. On the other hand, perhaps he's able to separate from his daemon (like Lyra now can), so it won't be so much of an issue?

Happy to have answers either from the books, from Phillip Pullman, or from the developers of the show.

Comment: All three TV series differ significantly from the books.  Series 3 is almost unrecognisable from the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably.

*The Amber Spyglass* follows Lyra's perspective, so the narrative never returns to Will's world after Kirjava is separated from Will - it follows Lyra to her own. Within the story, there's no confirmation one way or the other that people would be able to see Kirjava, as it never comes up.

Presumably other people would just see Kirjava as an ordinary cat. They would certainly be able to see something, as Will has no trouble seeing and talking to Pantalaimon. [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/242011) suggests that other people would be able to tell that the cat was unusual, or at least that other animals would, but lacks a source for this. It's also possible that humans with no concept of an external daemon would be unable to do this.

Comment: Dr. Malone's reaction to Pantalaimon would be a better indicator, but he appears to have been completely hidden during her and Lyra's meeting, and I don't think they meet again until the mulefa world. I can't think of anyone else Pantalaimon might have been exposed to.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's not explicitly mentioned in the book whether other people can see her. I think on balance you're right, she must be visible, since Will has no problem seeing daemons in both worlds, even before his own becomes visible.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the books, no, other people in our world can't see Kirjava. At least not by default.

I've not watched the series so, if you're planning to read the books, the following might be a spoiler.

Towards the end of The Amber Spyglass, Mary Malone speaks with the witch Serafina Pekkala. The witch teaches Mary to see her own dæmon. Later the witch says:

> When you are in your world, you will learn to see the dæmons of other people too, in the same way. They won't see yours or Will's, though, unless you teach them as I've taught you.

(p. 920, 38 The Botanic Garden, The Amber Spyglass)

Comment: This scene is in the TV show, and is actually the source of my confusion! So Mary needs to practice before she can see her demon, or anyone else's. But Will can see Pan as soon as he meets Lyra right? So is Will special in this respect, and anyone else from our world needs to train to see daemons? Seems like this might not be explicitly explained in the text... thanks for the answer anyway, very interesting!

Comment: Just to check - Mary never separates from her daemon, correct? So it makes sense that no one can see her daemon. And Serafina mentions seeing people's daemon in her world, where they're normally hidden, so I can understand needing to learn a special method to see them. Was Serafina aware that Will had separated from his daemon?

Comment: @qazmlpok Yes, she was. In ch. 36 she visits Will and Lyra's dæmons and they talk about the separation

Comment: @JayFor You're right that it's not really explained. I don't think Will is special in this respect. I think it's the other way around: dæmons of people from Lyra's world are visible by default. And dæmons of people from our world are hidden by default. To the point that Kirjava never needed a name before - so I presume she didn't talk to or even see other people's dæmons. They need to be uncovered through some kind of ritual (e.g. separation) or training. And even once uncovered, people in our world don't see them because it's not natural to them.

Comment: I think there is an element of perception or preconditioning. E.g. Will could see Mrs Coulter's monkey in our world. But perhaps that's because he heard about her dæmon before so he expected to see him. Maybe other people wouldn't see the monkey? Or it's a plot hole. The whole thing is rather inconsistent. When I read that Will's father met his dæmon in Lyra's world, I expected Will to see his too but that was not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Season 3 of that series has little to do with the book and misses lots of important elements. In the book, it's described like this: Witches perform a ritual of going into an area where dæemons cannot be, which makes them able to be so far apart. By going to the land of the dead, Lyra and Will did effectively the same. They are still connected, but the maximum distance between them is much larger, maybe even infinite. Kirjava is a regular dæmon since it was "ripped" out of Will while he was in the boat (which the series completely ignored), but with the same large distance. How exactly Will handles this after the story ends isn't specified, but I would guess that she most likely stays at home or goes on her own adventures.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that both Will and Lyra can separate from their daemons because they've been to the land of the dead. Regarding the 'ripping' in the show - the ferryman does say that Will will also be leaving a part of himself behind, but he doesn't show the same physical reaction Lyra does when the boat leaves, which I thought was an odd choice - will have to read the books too!